# Ubuntu terminal not using complete bandwidth

Tags: 16.04, bandwidth, tethering

I recently install Ubuntu 16.04 and have noticed that the terminal does not use my Internet connection to full capacity. While D/L speeds on my windows 10 go up to 500kBps (Torrenting) Ubuntu terminal rarely ever reaches 100kBps. is there someway to allow Ubuntu terminal unhindered access to the complete connection. The same effect is visible while installing extra drivers via settings app

PS: Both the OS use my Moto-E as their tether to the Internet

Update 1: I live in India and the download from is set to server for India. So I don't think geography is the culprit in this case

Comment: Please tell us the model name/number of your Moto-E device, and if possible, the wifi chip. You can also try to connect via wire (ethernet) and check if the speed is higher that way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors affecting the download speeds. If for example you're located in Germany, but your Ubuntu sources are set to look for data in US-based repositories, there will be slower download speeds.

You can look inside the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and look at the URLs there. Mine for example shows:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ artful main restricted
```

I'm located in the Czech Republic so repository located in my country makes sense. Geographical distance is not the only factor though...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu desktop, you should select best/nearest mirror from *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`):

1. Open *Software & Updates*
2. on *Ubuntu Software* tab set *Download from* to *Other*
3. choose server from your country or click *Select Best Server* (wait it for finish)
4. click *Choose Server*, enter your password and click *Authenticate*
5. click *Close* in *Software & Updates* and *Reload* in next windows.

These steps should select other mirror.